# Python for loop only running once?

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

This script looks interrogates a csv containing species names against a database in a csv and returns if they are in both. The issue is while it is still reading all the terms to search fine, it is only searching the first one. i.e. if I print speciesl before 'for row in p' all species names are returned correctly

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import csv

p = csv.reader(open('Paldat.csv','r',newline=''), delimiter=',')

with open('newsssssss.csv','r',newline='\n')as r:
    for line in r:
        taxons=line.split(',')
        no = ['\r\n']
        noo = ['\n']
        
        if taxons == no:
                continue
        elif taxons == noo:
                continue        
        else:
            speciesl = []
            for val in taxons:
                val = val.replace('\n','')
                speciesl.append(val)
            g=speciesl[0].lower()
            if len(speciesl) < 2:
                continue
            else:
                s=speciesl[1].lower()
        for row in p: #This loop seems to be the issue
                genus = row[0].lower()
                species = row[1].lower()
                if g == genus and s == species:
                    print('Perfect match')
                    print(g)
                elif s == species:
                    print(speciesl)
                    print('Species found')
                else:
                    continue
        else:
                continue
```

Here is part of Paldat.csv:

```
Camassia,leichtlinii,monad,monad,large (51-100 µm),-,-,-,-,-,sulcate,heteropolar,oblate,-,elliptic,-,-,boat-shaped,no suitable term,aperture(s) sunken,1,sulcus,sulcate,aperture membrane ornamented,-,-,-,"reticulate, heterobrochate, perforate",-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,present,,
Cistus,parviflorus,monad,monad,medium-sized (26-50 µm),-,-,-,-,-,colporate,isopolar,-,spheroidal,circular,-,-,spheroidal,circular,"aperture(s) sunken, not infolded",3,colporus,"colporate, tricolporate",-,-,-,-,striato-reticulate,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,absent,,
Camellia,japonica,monad,monad,medium-sized (26-50 µm),41-50 µm,36-40 µm,41-50 µm,41-50 µm,41-50 µm,colpate,isopolar,-,spheroidal,circular,oblique,prolate,-,triangular,aperture(s) sunken,3,colpus,"colpate, tricolpate",operculum,"granulate, scabrate, reticulate",-,-,microreticulate,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,,
Camellia,sinensis,monad,monad,medium-sized (26-50 µm),41-50 µm,36-40 µm,41-50 µm,41-50 µm,41-50 µm,colporate,isopolar,oblate,-,triangular,oblique,isodiametric,-,triangular,aperture(s) sunken,3,colporus,"colporate, tricolporate",operculum,"scabrate,  verrucate,  gemmate",-,-,"verrucate, perforate",-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,,
```

And part of newsssssss.csv:

```
Camassia,leichtlinii

Camellia,japonica

Camellia,sinensis

Chrysanthemum,leucanthemum

Cirsium,arvense

Cissus,quadrangularis
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
Your posted code is not minimal; it fails to run because of a private file, and you haven't traced the problem point.

Comment: Apologies. Should be fixed now

Comment: When you run the loop over `r` the first time you use `for row in p` to loop over the whole content of the file "Paldat.csv". In the following loops over `r` you already reached the end of `p` so no more lines will be read from that file.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!! - I put the `p=csv.reader(...paldat.csv...)` inside `for line in r` and it worked

Answer (score -1):

Try removing "newline='\n'" from the "open" line.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Same thing happened.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer, especially as it does not fix the problem.